# Django CORS, HTTPS and WSGI setup

Tags: django, https, cors, mod-wsgi, django-cors-headers

I am trying to setup CORS + HTTPS with mod_wsgi and Django but I can not get it to work.

CORS works properly without HTTPS/mod_wsgi but stops working when I try to add HTTPS/mod_wsgi.

For CORS, I use the Django CORS middleware (https://github.com/zestedesavoir/django-cors-middleware)

My Django middleware_classes is the following: (see CorsMiddleware and CorsPostCsrfMiddleware)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
]
```

I also add the following configuration:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

I run the Django/wsgi server as follow:

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 --https-port 8000 --ssl-certificate-file ../utils/ssl_cert/local.crt --ssl-certificate-key-file ../utils/ssl_cert/local.key --processes 8 --server-name localhost --https-only --reload-on-changes

Successfully ran command.
Server URL         : http://localhost:8001/
Server URL (HTTPS) : https://localhost:8000/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000/error_log (warn)
Request Capacity   : 40 (8 processes * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Startup Timeout    : 15 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 85 (event/worker), 70 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.UTF-8
```

If I query the HTTPS server with httpie from command line, it works as expected (no CORS issues of course).

If I query the HTTPS server from my web app, I get CORS issue:

```
OPTIONS https://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/auth-token/ 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/auth-token/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

In addition, the configuration generated for mod_wsgi server doesn't seem to set the headers to allow CORS

```
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000/httpd.conf
```

I am new to Django and I am not sure at which level should the CORS for HTTPS be configured.

I tried to configure it in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf unsuccessfully

```
<VirtualHost *>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

Best,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` does nothing for `mod_wsgi-express`. They are completely separate, with `mod_wsgi-express` ignoring any system Apache installation configuration files.

If you need to add that extra Apache httpd configuration directive when using `mod_wsgi-express`, add it to a file called `extra.conf` as just:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

and then run `mod_wsgi-express` as:

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 --https-port 8000 --ssl-certificate-file ../utils/ssl_cert/local.crt --ssl-certificate-key-file ../utils/ssl_cert/local.key --processes 8 --server-name localhost --https-only --reload-on-changes --include-file extra.conf
```

Comment: Thanks I believe this fixed the CORS issue but now running iunto another issue. I tries to access a file that doesn't exist. [authz_core:error] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000/htdocs/api.

Comment: What is in the ``/tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000/htdocs`` directory? Did you at any point play around with the ``--mount-point`` option to ``mod_wsgi-express``? If that directory isn't empty, and you didn't explicitly add anything in there, entirely remove the ``/tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000`` directory and start over.

Comment: I didn't touch any configuration. It seems that ```/tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000/htdocs``` is the DocumentRoot generated in ```/tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8001:1000/httpd.conf```. It seems the issue is that it tries to go to the ```api``` directory in it whereas ```api``` doesn't exist. ```api``` is in the url only for routing the REST API.... Thanks for your help

Comment: Which it shouldn't do. What version of Apache and mod_wsgi are you using? Can you put the generated ``httpd.conf`` file up in a ``gist`` somewhere so I can see it? Maybe take this conversation over to the mod_wsgi mailing list instead. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/finding-help.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't contact the mowsgi mailing list because I was not sure if I was misconfiguring mod_wsgi or Django. I also opened another SO issue for this specific problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490720/django-rest-wsgi-client-denied-by-server-configuration